# How to avoid JavaScript VM to be blocked by CPU bound task

Tags: javascript, node.js, cpu-usage

I have a cpu intensive task in JavaScript that is blocking the VM while executing within a `Promise`:

An example could be the following (try it out in the browser):

```
function task() {
   return new Promise((r,s) => {
      for(var x=0; x < 1000000*1000000; x++) {
          var Y = Math.sqrt(x/2)
      }
      return r(true)
   })
}
```

I would like to avoid the VM main thread to be blocked, so I have tried to detach using a `setTimeout` in the `Promise` passing the `resolve` and `reject` as context like:

```
function task() {
   return new Promise((r,s) => {
      var self=this;
      setTimeout( function(r,s) {
        for(var x=0; x < 1000000*1000000; x++) {
           var Y = Math.sqrt( Math.sin (x/2) + Math.cos(x/2))
         }
         return r(true);
      },500,r,s);
   })
}
```

but with no success. Any idea how to avoid the main thread to be stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to using web workers or similar, you can also (depending on the task) break up the work into smaller chunks that are worked on and scheduled using `setImmediate`. This example is a little silly, but you get the idea.

```
function brokenUpTask() {
  let x = 0;  // Keep track of progress here, not in the loop.
  const limit = 1000000;
  const chunk = 100000;
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    function tick() {  // Work a single chunk.
      let chunkLimit = Math.min(x + chunk, limit);
      for(x = 0; x < chunkLimit; x++) {
        var Y = Math.sqrt(x/2);
      }
      if(x === limit) {  // All done?
        resolve(true);
        return;
      }
      setImmediate(tick);  // Still work to do.
    }
    tick();  // Start work.
   });
}


brokenUpTask().then(() => console.log('ok'));
```

Comment: Thanks! My real world task is the LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) calculation in this specific case. See this implementation here: https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/07f3af8114a7a70169511351326064ae

Comment: Right. It looks like `gibbs` is the function that will end up taking the most time, so if you break the `iterations` loop there into a separate "step" function, that could be scheduled using `setImmediate`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Web Workers". That way, you stay conform with standard. This will basically be a background thread (for example like BackgroundWorker in older C#).

- [MDN Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)
- [Using Web Workers to Speed-Up Your JavaScript Applications](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-web-workers-to-speed-up-your-javascript-applications)

I am not sure if current node.js supports this nativly, so use
[npm web workers package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads)

Comment: that's a good idea and in the browser it could work for sure! I'm using it with a `node.cluster` process with N>1 workers, and running it in a `worker` or in the `master` is blocking the VM in the same way, so I should use something like web workers in node..